# Form submission with more than one file control

Tags: php, html

I tried to submit a form with more than one file control. But when submit the form, it is not submitted successfully. It is processing for long time without completion. I have the following code in .php file:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you taking so many inputs with same name you can take single only with multiple file upload, take array as name attribute

Comment: Actually, this is a demo of my problem. I have a large form with various file controls in the form. But whenever I use a more than one file control, form submission processing for long time.

Comment: ohhh. this not a problem you have to wait for the process, 
or you can change your configuration in php.ini

Comment: What I need to change in php.ini?

Comment: use different ids and names for inputs

Comment: I had given in answer

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets to the name attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: The problem is not solved even after using brackets.

Comment: This is a demo file I used. The problem is that whenever I used more than one FILE UPLOAD CONTROL, the processing become very slow. I tried <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> in action also.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this settings as per your requirement and also increase it,

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

this all settings are related to file upload.
i hope it helps.